# Plotting time intervals as segments

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, plot

I have the following dataframe:

```r
test_df <- structure(list(system = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "B", "B", 
"C", "B", "B", "A", "D", "D", "B", "E", NA, NA, "B", "A", "D"
), type = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), start_date = structure(c(16567, 
16604, 16324, 16595, 16111, 17597, 16784, 16648, 16121, 16549, 
16438, 16484, 15997, 16488, 16708, 16121, 16327, 16329, 17010, 
16342), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(16995, 16984, 
16661, 16909, 16414, 17843, 16990, 16853, 16323, 16751, 16622, 
16665, 16154, 16624, 16839, 16251, 16456, 16456, 17134, 16458
), class = "Date"), event_duration = c(428, 380, 337, 314, 303, 
246, 206, 205, 202, 202, 184, 181, 157, 136, 131, 130, 129, 127, 
124, 116)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
test_df
#>    system type start_date   end_date event_duration
#> 1       A    2 2015-05-12 2016-07-13            428
#> 2       B    2 2015-06-18 2016-07-02            380
#> 3       B    2 2014-09-11 2015-08-14            337
#> 4       C    2 2015-06-09 2016-04-18            314
#> 5       D    1 2014-02-10 2014-12-10            303
#> 6       B    1 2018-03-07 2018-11-08            246
#> 7       B    1 2015-12-15 2016-07-08            206
#> 8       C    2 2015-08-01 2016-02-22            205
#> 9       B    1 2014-02-20 2014-09-10            202
#> 10      B    2 2015-04-24 2015-11-12            202
#> 11      A    2 2015-01-03 2015-07-06            184
#> 12      D    2 2015-02-18 2015-08-18            181
#> 13      D    1 2013-10-19 2014-03-25            157
#> 14      B    2 2015-02-22 2015-07-08            136
#> 15      E    1 2015-09-30 2016-02-08            131
#> 16   <NA>    1 2014-02-20 2014-06-30            130
#> 17   <NA>    2 2014-09-14 2015-01-21            129
#> 18      B    2 2014-09-16 2015-01-21            127
#> 19      A    1 2016-07-28 2016-11-29            124
#> 20      D    1 2014-09-29 2015-01-23            116
```

For each `system`, I would like to plot differently colored sequences of segments, for each `type` of event, starting at `start_date` and ending at `end_date`. For example, for system `A`, I would like to plot two sequences of segments:

- one, corresponding to events of type 1, containing a single segment, which starts at `2016-07-28` and ends at `2016-11-29`
- another, corresponding to events of type 2, containing two segments, one starting at `2015-01-03` and ending at `2015-07-06`, and another starting at `2015-05-12` and ending at `2016-07-13`. As you see, events in a sequence can overlap. I'm not sure how to make sure that the user can still distinguish among events: maybe one could use arrows, or vertical bars or whatever, to show the start and the end of an event.

Ideally, the plots for each system should be in different facets, because I believe that having all of them in the same plot would make a complete mess (of course, the actual data frame is much bigger than this sample data frame).

For system `B`, I would have 3 segments corresponding to events of type 1, 5 corresponding to events of type 2. And so on. How can I create the plot I desire? I would prefer a `ggplot2` solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use jittering to avoid overplotting the start and end points. Whether this works well will depend on how many segments you're trying to plot.

To ensure you're able to adjust the y-direction of the lines the same amount, you can add the jitter to the df itself and use that to plot segments:

```
test_df$jitter <- jitter(test_df$type, amount = 0.25)

ggplot(test_df) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=start_date, xend=end_date, y=jitter, yend=jitter)) + 
  facet_wrap(~system) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(1,2), labels=c(1,2)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

You could also use start and end indicators as you suggested, to help emphasize the ends of the segments, but this may just add more noise if the number of segments is large.

```
ggplot(test_df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=start_date, y=jitter), size=1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=start_date, xend=end_date, y=jitter, yend=jitter), 
                   arrow=arrow(30,unit(1.25,"mm"),"last","closed")) + 
  facet_wrap(~system) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(1,2), labels=c(1,2)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

[image]